# how to add condition in $model->save() using YII

Tags: php, yii

```
<pre>
foreach($cons_name as $name){
$model = new Apps();
$model->const = $name;
$model->value =$value[$i];
$model->save();
}
</pre>
```

i am using this code how can i add some "where" conditions in this scenario. i am new to yii please tell me how to solve this issue. i am trying to save multiple records with the give code it is working for me but i want to add some more conditions to it.
also tell me how can i add multiple rows at a time instead of using loop

Comment: You cannot use a WHERE condition for INSERT's (that's what you're doing here), since it's a new row and there is nothing to search for.

Comment: See the answer below.

Comment: but first part of my question was i want to update and add some where coditions

Answer (score 3):

`$model = new Apps();` will create a new object for your model. If you want to edit an existing row, you should fetch the corresponding row using `find` method.

```
$model = Apps::model()->find('id=1 and type = 2');
```

As far as I know, you cannot insert multiple rows without using any loop in PHP. What you can do is build you insert query with multiple rows separated by comma and execute it once.

like

```
INSERT INTO table1 (id,name) VALUES (1,'NAME1'),(2,'NAME2'),(3,'NAME3')
```

Comment: should i use $model->save(); with above line?

Answer (score 0):

Because you use array with Active Record objects, you need foreach it and set necessary data for each object and then save. 
You can use method `ActiveRecord.updateAll();`